# Awk one-liner to print column of SQL table?

Tags: linux, awk, sql

Suppose I have table like:

```
This is first line
name                                minimum     maximum     config_value 
----------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------ 
some text goes here for sample                0           1            0 
Output Ends
```

The out should be like column 2nd:

```
minimum    
----------- 
          0
```

What will be the awk command to generate the output like this?

Comment: "This is first line" and "Output Ends" are in the table?

Comment: "This is first line" and "Output Ends" should not be visible in output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no awk guru, but if your output is always the same (I mean, second line is headers, and third line contains results), you can use something like this:

```
cat /tmp/test.txt | awk 'NR==2 {headers=$0; start=0; len=0} NR==3 { start=index($0," "); len=length($2)+1; print substr(headers,start,len) ; print substr($0,start,len)} NR==4 {print substr($0,start,len)}'
```

Since it's length delimited fields, you can get the starting index and length of your field by reading the "underline" line (`NR==3`).

If your SQL returns more than one line, so you'd have to use something like `if( NR > 1 && NR <= x )`.

Comment: Can we have an example which does not contain , in awk command? as I have to write this command in csv file.

Comment: @snoop : sorry, I'm not able to make it without comma. Can't you define another field separator for your CSV file? Otherway, are you really required to use `awk` only as @FloHimself specified?

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is not an substantial requirement, you could `cut` the file in pieces on fixed bytes (and `grep` away empty lines):

```
cut -b 37-47 data | grep -v '^$'
```

Comment: and `grep` away those first and last marker lines

Comment: Be careful that length of first column may vary depending on the "name" value.

Comment: And start byte and length might vary. Well, this is more an example for using `cut` to achieve what OP is asking for, based on the information the question offers, than an final solution.